# Select next column to right mysql?

Tags: mysql

If I have a variable in php like,

```
$var = 'aaa';
```

And my mysql database has 2 columns

```
| aaa | bbb |
```

Is there a way I can select bbb using `$var`, basically select the column next to `$var` on the right?

Comment: Is `aaa` a column name or a value in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {table}",$db)` to get a list of columns and use that to figure out the name of the column next to `aaa`. You can then use that in further queries.

Implementing this results in something in the lines of (untested):

```
$columns = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {table}",$db) or die("mysql error"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($columns) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($columns)) {
        if ($prev == 'aaa') {
            $nextcol = $row['Field']; // 'bbb' in this case
            break;
        }
        $prev = $row['Field'];
    }
}
```